# If $ a=e^{i\alpha}$ and $b=e^{i\beta} $ Show the following

Tags: complex-numbers, eulers-number-e

If $ a=e^{i\alpha}$ and $b=e^{i\beta} $, Show that
$$
    \frac{(a+b)(ab-1)}{(a-b)(ab+1)} = \frac{\sin(\alpha)+\sin(\beta)}{\sin(\alpha)-\sin(\beta)}
$$

Comment: I have edited your question to better conform to our [math formatting conventions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Note that I had to guess what was part of the numerators and denominators of the fractions. I think it aligns with what you had in your image, but please see that it is the way you intended.

Comment: Maybe have a shot at replacing $\sin(\alpha)=(a-\frac 1a)/2i$ and tackle it to get LHS ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint

$$\dfrac{a^2b-b}{ab^2-a}=\cdots=\dfrac{ab\left(a-\dfrac1a\right)}{ab\left(b-\dfrac1b\right)}=\cdots=\dfrac{2i\sin\alpha}{?}$$

Now apply [componendo dividendo](https://www.qc.edu.hk/math/Junior%20Secondary/Componendo%20et%20Dividendo.htm)

Comment: I have edited your post to hide the link ,i felt it looks better ,I hope you are fine with that

Comment: This is a nice one!